# How do i change input to act like div paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paypal

I have paypal multiple checkboxes form that based very much on Inputs.

I have the Sum displayed in **Input** and i want the Sum to be display in **Div** instead so i can decorate it with css.

Here is the code:

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
<!--
function Dollar (val) {  // force to valid dollar amount
var str,pos,rnd=0;
  if (val < .995) rnd = 1;  // for old Netscape browsers
  str = escape (val*1.0 + 0.005001 + rnd);  // float, round, escape
  pos = str.indexOf (".");
  if (pos > 0) str = str.substring (rnd, pos + 3);
  return str;
}function ReadForm (obj1, tst) { // process radio and checkbox
var i,j,amt=0,des="",obj,pos,val,tok,tag,
  op1a="",op1b="",op2a="",op2b="",itmn="";
var ary = new Array ();
  if (obj1.baseamt) amt  = obj1.baseamt.value*1.0;  // base amount
  if (obj1.basedes) des  = obj1.basedes.value;  // base description
  if (obj1.baseon0) op1a = obj1.baseon0.value;  // base options
  if (obj1.baseos0) op1b = obj1.baseos0.value;
  if (obj1.baseon1) op2a = obj1.baseon1.value;
  if (obj1.baseos1) op2b = obj1.baseos1.value;
  if (obj1.baseitn) itmn = obj1.baseitn.value;
  for (i=0; i<obj1.length; i++) {  // run entire form
    obj = obj1.elements[i];        // a form element
    if (obj.type == "checkbox" ||  // checkboxes
        obj.type == "radio") {     //  and radios
      if (obj.checked) {           // did user check it?
        val = obj.value;           // the value of the selection
        ary = val.split (" ");          // break apart
        for (j=0; j<ary.length; j++) {  // look at all items
// first we do single character tokens...
          if (ary[j].length < 2) continue;
          tok = ary[j].substring (0,1); // first character
          val = ary[j].substring (1);   // get data
          if (tok == "@") amt = val * 1.0;
          if (tok == "+") amt = amt + val*1.0;
          if (tok == "%") amt = amt + (amt * val/100.0);
          if (tok == "#") {             // record item number
            if (obj1.item_number) obj1.item_number.value = val;
          ary[j] = "";                // zap this array element
          }
// Now we do 3-character tokens...
          if (ary[j].length < 4) continue;
          tok = ary[j].substring (0,3); // first 3 chars
          val = ary[j].substring (3);   // get data
          if (tok == "s1=") {           // value for shipping
            if (obj1.shipping)  obj1.shipping.value  = val;
            ary[j] = "";                // clear it out
          }
          if (tok == "s2=") {           // value for shipping2
            if (obj1.shipping2) obj1.shipping2.value = val;
            ary[j] = "";                // clear it out
          }
        }
        val = ary.join (" ");           // rebuild val with what's left        tag = obj.name.substring (obj.name.length-2);  // get flag
        if      (tag == "1a") op1a = op1a + " " + val;
        else if (tag == "1b") op1b = op1b + " " + val;
        else if (tag == "2a") op2a = op2a + " " + val;
        else if (tag == "2b") op2b = op2b + " " + val;
        else if (tag == "3i") itmn = itmn + " " + val;
        else if (des.length == 0) des = val;
        else des = des + ", " + val;
      }
    }
  }
// Now summarize stuff we just processed, above
  if (op1a.length > 0) obj1.on0.value = op1a;
  if (op1b.length > 0) obj1.os0.value = op1b;
  if (op2a.length > 0) obj1.on1.value = op2a;
  if (op2b.length > 0) obj1.os1.value = op2b;
  if (itmn.length > 0) obj1.item_number.value = itmn;
  obj1.item_name.value = des;
  obj1.amount.value = Dollar (amt);
  if (obj1.tot) obj1.tot.value = "$" + Dollar (amt);
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
<!-- End of Script --> 

<body>

Pizza Order Form.

<br><br>

<!-- Another method for the View Cart Form - add this code anywhere within the web page -->

<!-- This is the FORM to view the cart contents -->
<!-- Note: target="paypal" was replaced with the variable target="_self" -->
<!-- Note: shopping_url also added to code -->
<!-- These two changes allow better functionality with IE and Firefox -->
<form target="_self" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="viewcart" name="viewcart">
<!-- If using a Business or Company Logo Graphic, include the "cpp_header_image" variable in your View Cart code. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="https://www.yourwebsite.com/logo.jpg">
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="display" value="1">
<!-- Replace "business" value with your PayPal Email Address or Account ID -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your @ emailaddress.com">
<!-- Replace value with the web page you want the customer to return to -->
<input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/Script_02.html">
</p>
</form>
<!-- End of the viewcart FORM -->




<!-- Start of Form -->
<!-- Note: target="paypal" was replaced with the variable target="_self" -->
<!-- Note: shopping_url also added to code -->
<!-- These two changes allow better functionality with IE and Firefox -->
<FORM onsubmit="this.target='_self';&#10; return ReadForm(this, true);" action=https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr method=post>
<!-- If using a Business or Company Logo Graphic, include the "cpp_header_image" variable in your View Cart code. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="https://www.yourwebsite.com/logo.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<!-- Replace "business" value with your PayPal Email Address or Account ID -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your @ emailaddress.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn/btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<!-- Replace value with the web page you want the customer to return to -->
<input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/Script_02.html">
<!-- Replace value with the web page you want the customer to return to after a successful transaction -->
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/ThankYou.html">
<!-- Replace value with the web page you want the customer to return to after item cancellation -->
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/Cancel.html">
<input type="hidden" value="0.00" name="baseamt">
<input type="hidden" value="Widget Lg Plain Pizza - @0.00" name="basedes">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHosted">


Add Toppings
<br><br>  
<input onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" type=checkbox value="Pepp +1.50"> Pepperoni - Add $1.50
<br><br>
<input onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" type=checkbox value="It Saug +1.50"> It Saugsage - Add $1.50
<br><br>
<input onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" type=checkbox value="Ons +1.10"> Onions - Add $1.10
<br><br>
<input onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" type=checkbox value="Mush +1.25"> Mushrooms - Add $1.25
<br><br>
<input onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" type=checkbox value="Gr Peppers +1.15"> Green Peppers - Add $1.15

<br><br>

<input class=nbor size=6 value=$0.00 name=tot> &nbsp; &nbsp;

<br>
<input type=image alt="cart add" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" name=submit>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">

<br><br>
<input onclick="document.forms.viewcart.target = '_self';&#10; document.forms.viewcart.submit ();&#10; return false;" type=image alt="cart view" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_viewcart_LG.gif">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"> 
</form>
```

I tried to change the **Input** of

```
<input class=nbor size=6 value=$0.00 name=tot>
```

to **Div** but it makes the **Sum** disappear and the form to not function.

Any suggestion?

See it here: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/dk7u31w0/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comment these two lines:

```
if (obj1.tot) obj1.tot.value = "$" + Dollar(amt);
<input class=nbor size=6 value=$0.00 name=tot>
```

add the following codes:

> html code:

```
<div class="display-amount"></div>
```

> javascript code:

```
var displayAmount = document.querySelector(".display-amount");
if (displayAmount) {
   displayAmount.firstChild.nodeValue = "$" + Dollar(amt);
}
```

Comment: I comment line `73, 161`, and line `77-80, 162`. see this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wL3aca4r/1/)

Comment: It has activeted the color style only. What about the font-family: arial; font-size: 16px; text-shadow: 4px solid black Style?

Comment: @StackBuck I think you should check how to write the correct `text-shadow` property in this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp), the font-family has changed to arial.

Comment: But how about the font decorations? They are correct.

Comment: write the CSS code in `.display-amount {}` to format what you want

Answer (score 0):

use a hidden input for the sum to work in the form and append a div with the same content to use for the display / styling

```
<input type="hidden" size="6" value="" name="tot">

<div id="totalAmount"></div>

//onform activity
$('[name=tot]').val(//total dollar amount);
$('#totalAmount').text(//'$'+total dollar amount)
```

Comment: Where exactly do i add the Javascript Code?

Comment: i don't know - I didn't really read your code. I was simply saying that one way of solving your issue would be to use an input for the form element and a div for the html element so that it can be styled. You will need to investigate where you can implement that if at all.  The idea would be to have the div at the end of the form where you are displaying the total and the input wherever your other hidden inputs and and then on changing the fom create a function that updates each with the new total. Therefore the js portion will go with the rest of your javascript code.